# Select DB records where some key values are the same

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB table `tab` with two key fields: `f1` and `f2`. Now I need to select all those entries from that table, where `f1` is the same for at least two entries (so only `f2` differs).

```
f1  |f2
----+----
a   |123
b   |123
c   |123
d   |123
b   |456
e   |123
c   |789
```

So in the example above, the SELECT should return all entries where `f1` = `b` or `c`. I tried it with the following SELECT, but that doesn't work:

```
SELECT f1, f2
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY f1, f2
HAVING count( f1 ) > 1
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count` in analytic version:

```
select f1, f2 
  from (
    select tab.*, count(1) over (partition by f1) cnt from tab 
    ) 
  where cnt>1
```

Results:

```
F1            F2
----- ----------
b            123
b            456
c            123
c            789
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine. Even though I have no idea what exactly you're doing here ;-)

Comment: Inner query contains information with all fields PLUS number of appearances of F1. Outer query filters results and selects only those which have count>1. More about analytic functions, partitioning, ordering [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php).

Answer (score 0):

This should work and look familiar to you:

```
SELECT f1, f2
FROM tab t1
WHERE f1 IN (SELECT f1 
             FROM tab t2 
             WHERE t1.f2 <> t2.f2)
```

Basically we check to see if `f1` is found again in itself where the `f2` does not match.

Comment: Couldn't one simply use `<>`?

Comment: @DavidFaber yep that would work, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

One can always use `EXISTS` in instances like these:

```
SELECT t1.f1, t2.f2 FROM tab t1
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tab t2
                 WHERE t2.f1 = t1.f1
                   AND t2.f2 <> t2.f2 );
```

But I personally would probably use the analytic version proposed by @PonderStibbons above.